Why does the "cp" command not work with pasted directory path from "pwd | pbcopy" command?
I ran pwd | pbcopy command in Terminal on my MacBook Pro to copy the working directory to the clipboard. The working directory looks like this:
/Users/JohnSmith/PycharmProjects/100 Days of Code - The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp2/Day 2/Type Error, Checking and Conversion

But when I change to another completely different directory, type cp  followed by CMD+V to paste the first directory path I get this error message:
cp: Conversion is not a directory

However, when I edit the clipboard content to append a forward slash character "/", I do not get the error message above. But when I then append the name of the file that I want to copy like this;
/Users/StephenLearmonth/PycharmProjects/100 Days of Code - The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp2/Day 2/Type Error, Checking and Conversion/task.py task-2.py

I get this error message:
cp: task-2.py is not a directory

It only copies the file task.py when I put double quotes around the directories in the copied directory path.
Is this a bug with Unix or the pwd | pbcopy command?
Anyone else had this problem?

This question is similar to: Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Change to a directory containing a space. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@muru No, that question doesn't discuss pasting at all. How to paste a snippet with special characters is a distinct question. I wouldn't be surprised if it's been asked before, but that's not the one.

It is not useful to have written the pwd command by the authors of Unix when it generates an output which is unusable to the cp command because the output of pwd can contain spaces or other  non-numeric and/or non-alphabetic characters which is unusable to the cp and other commands like cd.

@sjl26916091 The output of the pwd command is usable by the cp command. Your problem is that you did not tell the cp command to use the output of pwd as an argument. You instead told the shell to use the output of pwd as shell code. The output of pwd is a path, not shell code.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' What is “shellcode”? Wikipedia describes it as something used in hacking. The output of the pwd is not any kind of code - it’s a working directory path.

There is no bug. This is standard, expected behavior. While you, with your human brain, can understand that 100 Days of Code - The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp2 is a single directory, the shell just sees blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. It sees 10 words, 10 space separated strings, it has no way of knowing this is supposed to be one thing.
Basically, you need to tell the shell to treat that long string with many words as a single string. You do this by quoting:
cp "/Users/StephenLearmonth/PycharmProjects/100 Days of Code - The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp2/Day 2/Type Error, Checking and Conversion/task.py" task-2.py

So instead of typing cp and then Ctrl+V, you will need cp ", then paste, and then " to close the quote.

OK thanks @terdon.
It seems strange to me that the authors of the shell allow the shell to generate a directory path with the pwd command to include spaces with no double quotes surrounding the output of pwd knowing that this directoy path will cause an error when used with another command like cd.

When the shells were written there was no terminal window which you could have interacted with with a mouse or from which you would have been able to copy & paste. Nothing strange about it aside from your use-case. @sjl26916091

Also, @sjl26916091, pwd stands for print current directory. It isn't supposed to be put in a variable (that's what the standard $PWD variable is for).

Incorrect, pwd stands for print working directory.

I think you are missing the point @tink

Yes, sorry, @sjl26916091 I meant "working" as you said. The point was the print though. It's a tool designed to print a string, not format it for use by other programs. And anyway, this is a general issue: you should always use variables quoted and, if you do, something like cd "$PWD" would work.

No problem @terdon. What “tool” are you referring to? pwd is Unix command.

@sjl26916091 I don't really know what you mean by "UNIX command". The pwd tool can be a standalone executable (usually found in /sbin/pwd or /usr/bin/pwd) or it can be a shell builtin. In any case, it is a tool, written to do a specific thing and that thing isn't "to provide users with a string they can copy and use as input to another tool" but instead is "print the current directory to the terminal in a way that humans can read". Producing output for human consumption has different requirements to producing output for other tools.

@terdon OK, so on my macOS Monterey 12.7.6 MacBook Pro when I use the Terminal app and type pwd and cp am I executing a standalone executable or a shell builtin command?

Dunno, @sjl26916091. It depends on your setup. Most likely it's the builtin, but you can check by checking what comes first in the output of type -a pwd.

When you paste something in a terminal, are you pasting a snippet of shell code, or are you pasting a single argument to a command such as a file name?
Technically, pasting some text is equivalent to typing that text. As far as the shell is concerned, it receives input from the terminal, and it has no way to know whether that input came from pasting or from characters typed individually. So you can paste a whole command like
cp '/Users/StephenLearmonth/PycharmProjects/100 Days of Code - The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp2/Day 2/Type Error, Checking and Conversion/task.py' task-2.py

because you can type that command.
If you want to paste a single argument to a command, you need to convey to the shell the information “hey, now I'm going to enter a single file name, not a command”. In modern shells and terminals, this is possible with bracketed paste. When bracketed paste is enabled, the terminal sends an escape sequence to indicate that pasted text begins, and another escape sequence to indicate when it ends. The application running in the terminal, such as the shell, can then treat pasted text specially.
The macOS Terminal application supports bracketed paste, at least since Catalina (macOS 10.15). So does iTerm2. Zsh automatically enables bracketed paste. By default, the most visible aspect of bracketed paste in zsh is that what you just pasted is highlighted until you type something. The same feature also causes newlines to be inserted literally, rather than having each newline character cause the line to be executed immediately. (Also tabs are inserted literally rather than trigger completion.)
You can cause the bracketed text to be treated as a single argument rather than a single snippet by pressing Ctrl+U or Alt+0 or Esc 0 just before pasting. (On a mac, Alt is normally ⌥ option.) Any numerical argument other than 1 works, including Alt+- (which sets the numerical argument to 0). This tells zsh to add quotes around what you pasted.
Alternatively, instead of pasting, type "$(pbpaste)". This makes the pasted text (without trailing newlines, if any) used as a single command argument.

You aren’t reading my original question correctly.

@sjl26916091 No, I'm pretty sure I've read your question correctly. Your mental model of how a command line shell works is inconsistent, but my answer explains how it works. Think about how cp gets called. What decides to call the cp command and with what arguments? Answer: the shell. How does the shell determine what command it calls and with what arguments? Answer (in that specific example): everything up to the first space is the command name, then up to the second space is the first argument, and so on. What distinguishes a pasted space from a typed space? Well, nothing.

My point is that shell commands that produce output and accept input argument should be in a consistent format. This is not the case with the pwd command and the cp command.

@sjl26916091 it is consistent, you just need to use it correctly which means quoting. This has nothing to do with the specific commands, it is just how shells work: by default, they read space-separated things as separate things. You want many space separated things to be treated as one thing? Then you need to quote it.
